# Voter Rolls - Sqlite3 - SQL Query for Midterm elections

Tags: sqlite

I need a SQL query where I can sort the individuals by county and party voted

```
Table                             Fields
ILCongressional_6_Vote_History 
                               - signup_id
                               - voter_guid
                               - first_name
                               - last_name                                                       
                               - election_county
                               - election_state                 
                               - election_at
                               - ballot_vote_method
                               - ballot_party
                               - ballot_cast_at
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT election_county, ballot_party, signup_id, voter_guid, first_name, last_name
  FROM ILCongressional_6_Vote_History
 ORDER BY election_county, ballot_party
```

Add (or remove) columns as desired; I'd keep the columns used for the sort, just to know when you move from one party or county to another.

If that's not what you're looking for, then more data is probably required....